# contar las propiedades de un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una API q me trae algo parecido a esto como respuesta:

```
[{
    nombres: [{...}],
    status: true,
    tipo: ['A'],
  },
  {
    nombres: [{...}],
    status: false,
    tipo: ['B'],
  },
  {
    nombres: [{...}],
    status: true,
    tipo: ['A'],
  }]
```

Y tengo este codigo:

```
var result = array.reduce( (acc, arr) => (acc[arr.tipo] = (acc[arr.tipo] || 0) + 1, acc), {} );
```

pero el resultado lo trae asi:  `[{"A": 2}, {"B": 1}]`

Para poder mostrarlo de la forma requerida en la UI necesito q este asi:

```
[{tipo: 'A', count: 2}, {tipo: 'B', count: 1}]
```

Alguna idea de como hacer esto? No es obligatorio seguir el codigo mencionado solo necesito q se cree el objeto de esa manera

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que agregues el código que has intentado hacer para poder ayudarte. Si no, parece más bien una tarea.

Comment: De acuerdo, sería de gran ayuda que nos compartieras el código con el cual logras el resultado `[{"A": 2}, {"B": 1}]`, para poder ayudarte mas rápido

Comment: obtuve ese resultado cn este codigo: `var result = array.reduce( (acc, arr) => (acc[arr.tipo] = (acc[arr.tipo] || 0) + 1, acc), {} );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías modificarlo de la siguiente forma:

- Al `reduce` le pasamos un arreglo.
- Creamos un objeto para guardar el `tipo` como clave (`hashmap`).
- Si el `tipo` aún no esta en el objeto, lo creamos y también lo agregamos al arreglo.
- Finalmente aumentamos el contador.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let api = [{
  nombres: [{}],
  status: true,
  tipo: ['A'],
}, {
  nombres: [{}],
  status: false,
  tipo: ['B'],
}, {
  nombres: [{}],
  status: true,
  tipo: ['A'],
}];

var h = {}; // hashmap
var result = api.reduce((acc, {tipo}) => {
  let t = tipo[0]
  if (!h[t]) h[t] = {tipo: t, count: 0}, acc.push(h[t]);
  h[t].count++;
  return acc
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias! tu respuesta me ayudo mucho. :D

Answer (score 1):

utilizando tu mismo codigo, lo que hice fue: crear un `map` de tu `result` y de ahi obterner las `keys` del objeto. Despues de eso retornar el objeto con el resultado obtenido.

```js
let api = [{
  nombres: [{}],
  status: true,
  tipo: ['A'],
},
{
  nombres: [{}],
  status: false,
  tipo: ['B'],
},
{
  nombres: [{}],
  status: true,
  tipo: ['A'],
}];

var result = api.reduce( (acc, arr) => (acc[arr.tipo] = (acc[arr.tipo] || 0) + 1, acc), {} );

[result].map( (item) => {

  let result = Object.keys(item).map( (key) => {
    return {
      tipo: key,
      cantidad: item[key]
    }
  });

  console.log(result);

});
```

Pruebalo.